# 1 Picocuries per liter is how many millirems per year?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

How can you calculate how many millirems of radioactive particles occur per year? The measurements don't seem to match up with radon testing information.

333 millirems in a year not accounting for Radon in the basement.

In a 4 hour period, my basement was recorded at an average level of radon gas reaching 3.7 picocuries per liter. If someone spent 24 hours a day every day of the year, how many millirem total does that result?

Comment: Radon is particularly difficult, since it is primarily an alpha emitter. What this means is that all the radiation generated outside of your body contributes 0 millirem to you. Decays in your lungs will generate exposure, and given the volume of your lungs and how long you stay in the basement you could whip up an estimate.

Comment: @JonCuster in fact an almost exact duplicate of a (now closed) question by the same poster.

Comment: Yes, the forum said it was a homework question

Comment: Jon, can you give me some information how to calculate that exposure in millirems using this picocuries per liter information that is provided by the people who take the measurements?

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot more information than that as you are comparing two completely different quantities. The picocuries is related to the frequency of disintegrations, the rems are an effective dose, i.e. the absorbed radiation weighted by a damage factor according to the type of radiation. You should be able to get the weight easy enough, but the absorbed dose will not be trivial. What is the dimensions of your basement? What is the surface area of the person? What obstructions exist to shade the person from full exposure to the entire volume of gas? Thickness of clothing? How often is it washed?

It is a spectacularly complicated relationship, and in the end it is generally found heuristically; preferably by looking the value up in a book from the 1940s back when people could be bothered.

By the way, take care of the "...not accounting for Radon...", I wouldn't expect it to match up with Radon testing if it excludes it outright.

Comment: I am trying to accurately measure the exposure and add it to the millirems known, to see if it goes past a certain threshold.

Comment: Basement 1500sq ft, average male 6ft with normal sized lungs surface area, no obstructions, normal clothing washed daily.